# Which planets would be visible from the Saturn system using the Naked Eye?

Tags: astronomy, planets, estimation, solar-system

I was wondering which planets would be visible using the Naked Eye from Saturn? Would these planets always be visible or disappear as they got further from Saturn? Plus which planets wouldn't visible due to being indiscernible from the sun and would this affect people using early telescope to view these planets.

Comment: The nice open-source software [Stellarium](http://stellarium.org) lets you compute the apparent brightnesses (and locations) of celestial objects as viewed from locations other than Earth.

Comment: Stellarium is fabulous, but if don't want to install software, try NASA/JPL's solar system simulator: https://space.jpl.nasa.gov

Comment: Voyager 1 took an image of Earth from ~6 billion km (~40 AU or 5 times the Saturn-sun distance) famously called the [Pale Blue Dot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pale_Blue_Dot).  I am guessing the camera is slightly more sensitive than a human eye, but others could probably give more details.

Comment: I have installed Stellarium but how do I get a list of all the visible planet over a year on that planet?